# Binary search with lo and hi in pascal

Tags: pascal, freepascal

I want to create binary search in pascal. I have been struggling for hours to create this code and it's still not complete. Could someone please help me out

```
program binSearch;
uses crt;

TYPE index=1..100;
VAR  arr:ARRAY[1..100] OF index;
var lo,hi,search,m,n:integer;

begin
write('n: ');
read(n);

     lo:=1;
     hi:=n;
     while (lo <> hi) do
     begin
           m:=(lo+hi) DIV 2;
           if (arr[m]<search) then
           lo:=m+1
           else
           hi:=m;
     end

     if (arr[lo]<> search) then
     index:=-1
     else
     index:=lo;

end.
```

This is what i found on the internet but this code only tell you if the number the user wants to search is found or not.

```
PROGRAM binary_search;

USES crt;
TYPE index=1..100; 
VAR  arr:ARRAY[1..100] OF index; 
VAR  mid,low,high,search:integer; 
     i,n:index; 
     found:boolean;
BEGIN 
     clrscr; 
     writeln('Binary search');
     writeln('array lengt:');
     readln(n); 
     writeln('Enter ',n,' numbers: ');
     FOR i:=1 TO n DO 
     BEGIN 
          readln(arr[i]); 
     END; 
     writeln('what number do you want to search?');
     readln(search); 
     low:=1; 
     high:=n; 
     found:=false; 
     REPEAT 
           mid:=trunc(low+high) DIV 2; 
           IF (search<arr[mid]) THEN 
           high:=mid-1; 
           IF (search>arr[mid]) THEN 
           low:=mid+1; 
           IF (search=arr[mid]) THEN 
           found:=true 
           ELSE 
           found:=false; 
     UNTIL ((found=true) OR (high<low)); 
     IF found=true THEN writeln('ELEMENT FOUND')
     ELSE writeln('ELEMENT NOT FOUND');
     readkey();
END.
```

Comment: @bhspencer yeah man i know pascal is an old software, but i really need it and i'm sure some people here know the language.

Comment: [Binary search at Rosetta](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Binary_search#Pascal) PS: The previous Q about freepascal was asked 15 hours ago, there are 3 Q about Delphi today for the moment. Do not believe the propaganda - believe the facts! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code can be changed easily to get the index of a found element (note that I wrote **a not the** because there may be more than one element with the search value): You just plugin the index of the compared element if the values are the same, this additionally improves the code. Another hint is that you should avoid the test of booleans to `false/true`: Just use them, i.e. in your code use 
`UNTIL found OR (high<low)` instead of `UNTIL((found=true) OR (high<low))`.
Further try to avoid predefined names like `high` or `low`. Here my adjustments to your code. As already said, there is some ambiguity in finding *the* index of an element: If you search the five elements 1 2 2 3 4 for the value 2 the program returns the index 3 not 2.

```
program binary_search;

uses
  crt;
type
  index=1..100;
var
  arr:array[1..100] of index;
var
  mid,ilow,ihigh,search:integer;
  i,n,fi:index;
  found:boolean;
begin
  clrscr;
  writeln('Binary search');
  writeln('array length:');
  readln(n);
  writeln('Enter ',n,' numbers: ');
  for i:=1 to n do begin
    readln(arr[i]);
  end;
  writeln('what number do you want to search?');
  readln(search);
  ilow  :=1;
  ihigh :=n;
  found :=false;
  repeat
    mid := (ilow+ihigh) div 2;
    if search=arr[mid] then begin
      //Element found, record the index in fi and break the search loop
      found := true;
      fi := mid;
      break;
    end
    else if search<arr[mid] then ihigh := mid-1
    else ilow := mid+1;
  until ihigh < ilow;
  if found then writeln('Element found, Index = ', fi)
  else writeln('Element NOT found');
  readkey();
end.
```